# How to pass dynamic amount of data in jQuery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=parseLink("modules/Contacts/output/output.php")?>',
  data: { 
    $('.contacts-block-input-text').each(function(){
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      value: $(this).val()
    })
  },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
    $('.resultMessage').text(result)
  }
})
```

So there will be dynamic amount of input fields and I need to gather all the `contacts-block-input-text` values and pass them in the `data` field somehow. How could I do this? The given example doesn't work.

Comment: `data` accepts a string or an object. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve with your usage of `each()` in there. Can you give some details about what data your `output.php` is expecting to receive.

Comment: Why don't you just serialize these inputs? Set a name attribute to each ones if none already set then use `data: $('.contacts-block-input-text').serialize(),`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to build an array, collecting your input data:

```
var myData = [];
$('.contacts-block-input-text').each(function(){
  myData.push({
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      value: $(this).val()
  });
});
```

Then you can use `myData` to pass it to the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?=parseLink("modules/Contacts/output/output.php")?>',
  data: myData,
  type: 'post',
  success: function(result){
    $('.resultMessage').text(result)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate through your jQuery array, combine the data object, and then pass it to AJAX call:

```
var d = [];
$(".contacts-block-input-text").each(function() {
    d.push({ id: this.id, value: this.value });
});    

$.ajax({
    data: d
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to generate a data object and pass it over to the `ajax` method, as below.

```
var myData = $('.contacts-block-input-text').map(function() {
    return { 'id': this.id, 'value': this.value };
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: '....',
    data: myData,
    //and so on... 
});
```